# How to write itertools.izip to txt file one by line?

Tags: python, python-itertools

My code

```
import itertools
import os

with open("base.txt") as fv, open("new2.txt", 'r') as fi, open('sortedf.txt','w') as fs:
    vel = (line.strip() for line in fv)
    ind = (int(line.strip()) for line in fi)
    z = itertools.izip(ind, vel) # sort according to ind
    # itertools.izip(vel, ind) # sort according to vel
    for i, v in sorted(z):
        fs.write(str(v))
```

I got everything on one line

```
2.900000e+032.900000e+032.900000e+032.900000e+032.
```

When I change to
 `fs.write('\n'.join(str(v)))`

Then I got

```
2
.
9
0
0
0
0
0
e
+
0
32
.
9
0
0
0
0
0
e
+
0
32
.
```

How to get proper one by line value output?

Comment: You want a newline after each line, right? So how about `fs.write(str(v)+'\n')` ?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes that is the wright format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Change

```
for i, v in sorted(z):
    fs.write(str(v))
```

to

```
for i,v in sorted(z):
    print(v, file=fs)
```

- `\n` is added automatically due to the `end="\n"` default parameter of `print`
- works for any datatype. No need for `str(v)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
fs.writelines(map(lambda x: x[1], sorted(z)))
```

Why below statement failed

```
fs.write('\n'.join(str(v)))
```

Here v, is converted into a list and join is applied over it. Look at below example for clarity

```
>>> sam = 'hello'
>>> '-'.join(sam)
'h-e-l-l-o'
```

so how to use fs.write ?

1. write just as : fs.write(v)
2. now add linebreak : fs.write('\n')

Few suggestions:

```
import os # load important modules first

from itertools import izip # makes processing faster, if you only need izip 


with open("base.txt") as fv, open("new2.txt", 'r') as fi, open('sortedf.txt','w') as fs:
    vel = [line.strip() for line in fv] # use square braces
    ind = int(line.strip()) for line in fi] # use square braces
    z = izip(ind, vel) # sort according to ind
    for i, v in sorted(z):
        fs.write(v)
        fs.write('\n') # adding line break
```